# 'LIKE' expression on JSONB column with CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, criteriaquery

I am trying to use JSONB with CriteriaQuery, and trying to implement this query in terms of criteria builder:

```
select *
from customer
where exists (
              select true
              from jsonb_array_elements(customer.contacts::jsonb)
              where value::text like '%2%'
          );
```

But seems to be there is no way, in criteria query, to have correlated subquery from function execution result.

Do you know how to implement this query in criteria query or how to make a 'LIKE' expression against JSONB column?

JSONB column has following format: `[{"type": "PHONE", "value": "1122"}, {"type": "PHONE", "value": "3344"}]`;

The query should be a criteria query instance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select *
  from customer
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(contacts) as x(jcontact)
 where jcontact->>'value' like '%2%';
```

Have a look at the results.  You will get multiple rows if there is more than one contact that has `value like '%2%'`, but you can eliminate those with `distinct` and restricting to the columns you actually need.

As for HIbernate or criteriaquery, I cannot help you there.  ORMs are a really bad idea.